# How can we test /user/show?id=xx with rspec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, controller, routes

The route in my system is:

```
user_show GET /user/show(.:format)  user#show.
```

The controller code is:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user}
    end
end
```

_spec.rb

```
describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'should return success' do
        get :show, id:@user.id
        expect(response).to be_success
    end
end
```

result is:

> Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_success
>
> expected success? to return true, got false

In the browser, when I type xxx/user/show, it get error.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UserController#show

But if I type xxx/user/show?id=31, it shows user with id=31!!

Thanks for @Alex Wayne, I add more information here: I check the routes.rb file:

```
  get "user/show"
  get "user/index"
  get "user/delete"
  get "user/edit"
  post "user/update"
  resource :users, :path => :user, :as => :user
```

I personal think my teammate should not write down "get user/show, get user/index...."  based on [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). But I can't change their code. So,
anyone know how to test user/show?id=xxx  ? Many thanks~!!!!

Comment: Why use a route like that? Typically, if you want to show a resource by it's id, you would use the `resource` route generators which let you run the `show` action on a route like `/users/123`.

Comment: it won't work too: No route matches [GET] "/user/show/123"

Comment: and "No route matches [GET] "/user/123"...@@

Comment: Well how did you declare this route?

Comment: I check the routes.rb file, find that my teammate put:"resource :users, :path => :user, :as => :user", and "get 'user/show'". If I commend "get 'user/show'", /user/show/123, /user/123/, and /user/show?id=123 are **all not** working~! Problem could coming from here?

Comment: After reading your question again, I deleted my answer, but I will say this here: your routes are fighting against both Rails and REST convention by trying to be singular instead of plural.  The proper RESTful route for `show`, which Rails follows by convention, and which a simple `resources :users` will create, is `/users/123/show` (or simply `/users/123`).  Trying to turn that into `/user/123/show` is going to cause problems.  All those `get` routes are going to conflict with the `resources :users, :path => :user` as well, which is trying to create mis-named RESTful routes that take an id.

Comment: Thank you @JimStewart, I was also thinking why putting both get and resource at routes.rb would cause problem. Your answer is very helpful :)